Didn't enter root password correctly on Linux after installing new NVIDIA drivers. Now NVIDIA drivers won't work
I was trying to install the newest NVIDIA drivers, version 550.78. I'm VERY new to Linux and I've been struggling with this for a few hours. I finally found a solution that worked through the terminal, it asked me for a new password, asked me to reboot after and enter the password after the reboot to make sure it wasn't an attack or something. I think I messed up, maybe I wasn't paying enough attention but at the time I thought I didn't get the option to enter the security password. When I logged in I checked NVIDIA X server settings, almost completely blank.
I checked the terminal:
nvidia-smi won't work because "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."
prime-select query gives me "on-demand"
sudo prime-select intel gives me "Error: no integrated GPU detected."
prime-select nvidia gives me "This operation requires root privileges"
Update: After a bunch of experimenting I figured out what happened has nothing to do with the password incident and instead is some conflict between Ubuntu 24.04 and Nvidia's version 545 and 550 drivers. We haven't fixed the problem, everything we've tried has failed, even trying to replicate the problem on other people's computers and on VMs we're not really sure what to do. If any of you want to or can guide me in the right direction to actually fix this that would be greatly appreciated.

What version of Ubuntu are you running? (24.04 has known problems with 545 and 550 drivers).  Where did you get the 550.78 driver?  What gpu do you have.  Did you turn off secure boot?  Add requested information to your original posting.

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
When I was first struggling with it I tried to get the update through the official website but when that wasn't working I managed to get it through the terminal.
I'm not sure how to find What GPU I have, I typed in lshw but because I'm very new I wasn't sure where to find it in that list it gave.
I don't think I turned off secure boot

If you’re new to Linux, I’d recommend going with 22.04LTS - it’s been around for long enough for many bugs to be ironed out. It’s stable, works well and will be fully supported for 3 more years. Seems like lots of issues with 24.04 that haven’t yet been sorted.

Being very new to Ubuntu, I suggest you delete as root and re-install as user.
1/ Install the Synaptic GUI...
a/ open the Terminal and enter: sudo apt install synaptic
2/ Open Synaptic as root...
a/ open Terminal and enter: sudo synaptic
b/ click the menus: settings -> repositories -> additional drivers
c/ click the button for Nouveau display driver
d/ save and close
3/ Purge Nvidia...
a/ in Terminal, enter: sudo apt purge nvidia*
4/ reboot and login as user
5/ To re-install, open Synaptic...
a/ click menu button: Search
b/ enter Nvidia
c/ select the meta package for the driver you need. example: nvidia-driver-550.
d/ click menu button: Apply
e/ close
6/ reboot as user
Is system working? - done.
To verify driver, open Synaptic, then menus: settings -> repositories -> additional drivers
Synaptic should show the Nvidia driver installed and active.

It's giving me back a bunch of errors when I try and do the 1st thing and the 2nd thing isn't working
The errors for the 1st thing:
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-545.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
nvidia-dkms-545
nvidia-driver-545
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Nvidia can be a major problem. The community is trying to help you, but you must help us to help you. You have not noted your hardware, software, the versions, nor how you arrived at your problem. Example: have you a laptop on which you are attempting to dual boot with windows? ...cont.d...

... However, as your system cannot run a basic command like, "sudo apt install xx", then something is seriously wrong with your install or system. Your choice is either; spend weeks or months trying to debug; or wiping what you have by installing a fresh Linux distro. Given you are newbie, and the problems with Nvidia, I suggest you install a distro known to be Nvidia compatible out-of-the-box.  ...

... For a laptop, Linux Mint works well, but can sometimes present problems with Nvidia. The best I have found for Nvida compatibility is the Pop_OS! distro, which installs in about 20 minutes. (to all the haters out there, I know Pop may be sacrilegious to suggest in this Ubuntu forum, please forgive, but the priority is to help a newbie get into the Linux world easily).
